# JQuery tabs no longer showing the tabs

Tags: jquery, maps

i had the info windows showing the tabs just fine a few weeks ago..and now its not showing anymore...
In fact the code uses JQuery..
find the codes on this link 
http://code.google.com/p/gmaps-samples-v3/source/browse/trunk/infowindow/tabs.html?r=78

I have included all the libraries og JQuery including the CSS files..what is wrong?...
what puzzles me is that it was working for quite a while and suddenly stopped..what actually happened??
Any help would be appreciated:)

Here is the updated code:(but it doesn't really work)

> ```
> google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
>   infowindow.open(map, marker);
> ```

```
  //$("#tabs").tabs();
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs();
  }, 100);
});
```

Comment: hi memke...the code is in the link...please find it....:)

Comment: Yes, I found it, I got 3 warnings in google chrome developer regarding  js scripts

Comment: When did you add this jquery-ui custom rc. I think it's broken. Open Firefox Error Console and you will see

Comment: maybe u forgot to include the jQuery files...??

Comment: then which files should i include??

Comment: Have you changed anything in code, since the time it worked fine?

Comment: nops...i downloaded the Jquery files and it worked fine....did you try the code?..the tabs work?..i mean do they show or are they in bullet form?

Comment: Nope, they are in the bullet form, not working

Comment: but what should i do to get it to work as before..this is queer...i mean it was working and now it doesn't work anymore..what actually has changed?..it must be the jQuery files right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a work–around:

Change this:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  $("#tabs").tabs();
});
```

to:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
  infowindow.open(map, marker);
  // Wait for 50ms until converting tabs
  setTimeout(function(){
    $("#tabs").tabs();
  }, 50);
});
```

You might have to choose a greater value than **50**. Seems that the tabs content is available but can't be transformed right away (I'd blame google maps). Better would be to find an event that's triggered once the infowindow has set the content and *then* call the `tabs()` method.

Comment: No problem. (OT: You might want to make use of the `edit` function for comments as well ;) ) I'll update my answer to clarify.

Comment: oww..now i see...i'll try it straight away..:p

Comment: praneeth..have you checked the codes?...in the link i put above?..please do...coz it's not working for me:-s

Comment: Increase the timeout time and see if that helps. Images shouldn't matter. Please use comments for feedback, this is not an answer.

Comment: google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
   
      //$("#tabs").tabs();
   setTimeout(function(){
  $("#tabs").tabs();
   }, 100);
    });

Comment: i increased it and it still doesn't work...did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, I had downloaded your files and tried it. Worked fine. Try a much bigger value to see if that's your problem to begin with. 1000–5000.

Comment: StackOverflow is not a forum.  You should ask a separate question.